# How to parse SVG source into React node?

Tags: reactjs

I'm not asking how to embed SVG file or image in React. I need a function of following type signature:

```
(source: string) => React.ReactNode
```

This function parse SVG source string and returns a React node. I really need this because I'm handling the output of Graphviz. And because I want to manipulate the resulting React node, `dangerouslySetInnerHtml` cannot meet my requirements.

Of course, I can parse the SVG source to `SVGElement` by `DOMParser` and then translate native `SVGElement` nodes into `ReactElement`. But this costs time. I wonder if anyone did this job before? I searched the whole Internet but gained nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about performance. But maybe smth like https://github.com/egoist/svg-to-component or https://github.com/publitas/svg-to-react.